# How to safely modify string from another thread in C with pthreads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, race-condition

I am trying to create a simple CLI music player in C. I have created a second thread aside from the main thread which is responsible for playing the music. The second thread receives an argument like so (I have tried with and without the volatile keyword):

```
typedef struct AUDIO_S
{
    volatile char audio_path[MAX_PATH];
    volatile int play_state;
} audio_t;
```

The main thread may update both the audio path (current file) and the play state (playing/paused). The job of the second thread is to detect this change and act accordingly by changing, playing, or pausing the song.

I have an issue where what (I assume) is happening is that the second thread reads this data at the same time as it is being written to by the main thread, which is producing garbled output. I tried implementing a conditional variable but I'm still getting bad output.

Here is the code where I write the data:

```
extern pthread_mutex_t mutex;
extern pthread_cond_t cond;

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

strcpy(audio->audio_path, state->cur_play_dir);
strcat(audio->audio_path, "/");
strcat(audio->audio_path, state->cur_play_file);
audio->play_state = MUSIC_PLAY;

pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

And here is the code where I read it:

```
extern pthread_mutex_t mutex;
extern pthread_cond_t cond;

while (1)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);

    char *new_audio_path = audio->audio_path;
    if (strcmp(new_audio_path, cur_audio_path))
    {               
        cur_audio_path = realloc(cur_audio_path,
                                strlen(new_audio_path) + 1);

        strcpy(cur_audio_path, audio->audio_path);
        printw("PATH: %s\n", cur_audio_path);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

The mutex and the condition are declared as global variables like so:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

I'm fairly new to parallel programming so I suspect I'm doing something glaringly obvious and stupid.

Comment: `volatile` does not address thread synchronization, and should not be used for that purpose in C.  You appear to be using a mutex correctly for that purpose, so if you have presented a faithful representation of the only accesses to the data in question then I don't think yours is a synchronization problem.

Comment: I do note that you fail to test whether the `realloc()` succeeds before you proceed with using its result.  Possibly that is related to your issue.

Comment: Overall, we will probably need a [mre] to be of much help.

Comment: I do not have my computer right now but a good YouTube channel is Jacob Sorber one. You may want to have a look at this video : https://youtu.be/9axu8CUvOKY I think it can help you.

Comment: My first guess is that you should also check the return status from `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);` as it _can fail_. However, it's a very weak probability. At second hand, you should check that you're using the _same_ mutex instance in both parts of your code. How do you share the mutex ? As a static declaration in common library or do you have 'all' in one executable only ?

Answer (score 1):

After sleeping on the issue I realised my mistake. As it turns out there was actually no issue at all with the data stored in the path string.

In the second thread I was printing the value of the path to stdout purely to check that the value was valid (so I forgot to lock anything). However, in the main thread, I was also printing other data to stdout.

With two threads both writing to stdout the data appeared garbled when printed when in reality there was no issue with the data stored in memory. I verified this by instead writing to a text file in the second thread while the first thread wrote to stdout. The data written to the text file had no issues.